# How to add break line in string.Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I was trying to add a break line in `string.Format`. However it didn't work no matter I added  `\r\n` or `Environment.NewLine`. Can anyone advise what is the proper way to add a break line into the statement? Thanks.

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity;
            var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            var userFromDb = await _db.ApplicationUser.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == claim.Value);
            var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(userFromDb);
            string r = string.Format("{0} \r\n ({1})", userFromDb.Name, role[0]);
            return View("Default",r);
        }
```

Comment: You can break a line by `<br />` in html. You should change your code like this:
`string.Format("{0} <br /> {1}", userFromDb.Name, role[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

`\r\n` this work in C# code

```
    string Name  = "Alex";
    var role = "manager";

    string newString = string.Format("{0} \r\n ({1})", Name, role);
    Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

however if you want to return `view` so it must be `html` break line `<br />`

```
public static class BreakLine
{
    public const string LineBreak = @"<br />";
}
string htmlString  =  string.Format(@"{0} {1} ({2})", Name, BreakLine.LineBreak, role);
    Console.WriteLine(htmlString);
```

Comment: Suggesting to implement script injection is ... not exactly the nicest thing one can do...

Answer (score 1):

Your controller (or view component) shouldn’t actually be responsible for deciding how something is displayed. Whether you need for example a line break, a `<br />` tag, or separate `<p>` tags is the responsibility of the *view*. So you should not attempt to solve this in the controller but instead pass the view just everything necessary to take care of the visual representation itself.

You can do that by create a custom view model that contains the values you need to pass the view. You then create this view model and set its properties and pass on the object to the view:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity;
    var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

    var userFromDb = await _db.ApplicationUser.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == claim.Value);
    var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(userFromDb);

    // pass a complex object with separate properties to the view instead
    return View("Default", new MyViewComponentModel
    {
        Name = userFromDb.Name,
        Role = role[0],
    });
}

public class MyViewComponentModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the view, specify this `MyViewComponentModel` as the view model type and access the properties to render the values properly:

```
@model MyViewComponentModel

<div>
    <strong>@Model.Name</strong><br />
    @Model.Role
</div>
```

This approach has another huge benefit over creating the HTML code in the controller code: If you were to pass HTML to the view, then the view would have to render that text as *raw HTML*. This means that the code is taken as it is and no HTML encoding happens with the content. This may work with save values that are coming from your database but can get dangerous very quickly as soon as there is some user-defined content in there. Then, you are basically allowing malicious users to decide what kind of HTML gets rendered on your website which is a very common security issue. So it’s best to avoid that and have as little raw HTML in your views as absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the line-break and sending the string to an HTML view. HTML is white space agnostic. Line-breaks are white space. Therefore the line-break has zero effect on the displayed string.

To place a line-break in HTML use the <br> tag. Or, better still send the string as two strings and let the view decide how it is displayed.